# Copying Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code on my chrome developer console

```
array = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
copyarray = array
[1, 2, 3]
copyarray = [1]
[1]
array
[1, 2, 3]
copyarray = array 
[1, 2, 3]
copyarray
[1, 2, 3]
copyarray.pop()
3
copyarray
[1, 2]
array
[1, 2]
copyarray+''
"1,2"
copyarray = copyarray +''
"1,2"
array
[1, 2]
```

Can anyone tell the reason why value of "array" changes when i use use some Array methods(like pop splice etc.) on "copyarray" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase these are references.  You can however do this, which will clone the array.

```
var copyarray = array.slice(0);
```

instead of:

```
copyarray = array
```

Another option is to create a prototype.

```
Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    return this.slice(0);
};

var copyarray = array.clone();
```

Comment: But why it is not true in case of a string 
like var 
str1 = 'jeswin   ';
str2 = str1;
str2.trim()
str1 now remains unchanged

Answer (score 3):

Because when you assign the value of one variable to the other, you're making a copy of a **reference** to the (single) array object. JavaScript does not provide a primitive operation for making a complete copy of an object. The closest is probably the `.slice()` method on arrays:

```
var copyarray = array.slice(0);
```

Now there are two arrays, and modifications to one won't affect the other.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript assigns objects by reference, not by value. You have two *names* referring to the same object.

It sounds like you want to [*clone* your array](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array).

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your answer, so that it doesn't become useless if (or when) the link rots away.

Answer (score 0):

well copyarray and array both point to the same array object, and on the other hand methods pop and splice (not slice) modify the array at hand directly. So if you apply any of these methods on an instance, that instance will be modified and as a result all the variables pointing to that array will be pointing to that modified version of that array.