# copying an integer array to a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have an integer array

```
let arr=[7,1,5,3,6,4]
```

i am using this array to sort it in ascending order and extract the position of the first smallest element in the original array.My function is defined as

```
const maxProfit = function(prices) {
    let org=prices
    prices.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b})
    console.log(org)
    let ind=org.indexOf(prices[0])
    console.log(ind) 
};

console.log(maxProfit([7,1,5,3,6,4]))
```

i was interested in the value of org which is suppose to be [7,1,5,3,6,4] instead i got it as [1,3,4,5,6,7] why the assigning of the original array not working here?

Comment: This `let org=prices` doesn't clone the array. It's the same (now sorted) array.

Comment: `let org = prices.slice()`.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366619/copying-javascript-array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not primitive types and can't be cloned with `=` operator.
For a relatively small array, you can just simply clone it like this

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let newArr = arr.slice()
```

now you can perform whatever you want on `newArr` and it will not affect the original array